# Django: How to fix <Response [403]> when using django send_mail() function?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to send a news letter broadcast email, i am getting all the email lists successfully from the db but the error seems to pointing to django `send_mail()` or is there something else that i am missing?

```
    def(...):
        ...
        emails = NewsLetter.objects.all()
        df = read_frame(emails, fieldnames=['email'])
        mail_list = df['email'].values.tolist()
        print(mail_list)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MailMessageForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
                message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
                send_mail(
                    title,
                    message,
                    '',
                    mail_list,
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
                messages.success(request, 'Message has been sent to the Mail List')
                return redirect('mail-letter')
        else:
            form = MailMessageForm()
```

template

```
<form  method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input required id="full_name" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Subject">
    <textarea required id="message" name="message" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <button class="submit-btn def-btn w-100" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code 403 indicates that there is the Permission Denied exception. So the first step to debug this issue would be to check if there are any restrictions that block the processing of the POST request.

It would also be a good idea to provide more details about the conditions under which the error occurs, this way the answers will be far more instructive.

Comment: @it occurs when i want to send email but this time around to mass email addresses, initially when i do `['desti@gmail.com']`, it gets sent, but if i now pass in the variable that is getting all the email, it doesn't e.g `username`

Comment: @DestinyFranks do you know at which stage the function fails? You could add some prints to check out. Also, it may be helpful to print out the variable to make sure it contains exactly what you expect.